# how do i capture customed annotated Class during jackson deserialization via customed JsonDeserializer

Tags: jackson, deserialization

i need to create a deserializer for common string.class type.the main purpose as fellow:

- capture the annotated property to do some tranformer effective to the string
- strip the known invalid characters sequence produced by programming language.(eg. null,nil ,undefined etc.)

i've read the related source code of jackson（v2.9.6),and can not find out solution,anyone can help me?

while the mainly code looks like bellow:

#### StringOptimizing

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonAnnotationsInside;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

/**
 * @author: passedbylove
 * @date: Created by  2023/1/12 12:18
 * @version: 1.0.0
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
public @interface StringOptimizing {

    EffectFeature[] usingFeature() default {};
    enum EffectFeature
    {
        /***
         * full with to half width transformer
         */
        FullWidthToHalfWidth,
        /***
         * half width tofull with transformer
         */
        HalfWidthToFullWidth,

        /***
         *  strip the head & tail Unicode null Code point(\u0000) from a string instance.
         */
        TrimUnicodeNullCodePoint,

        /***
         * do html escape to prevent XSS attach
         */
        HtmlEscape,

        /***
         * do html unescape stuff
         */
        HtmlUnEscape,
        /***
         * sql injection detection by Policy,reference from <a href="https://github.com/rkpunjal/sql-injection-safe">Annotation and Utility to check if data Strings are Sql-Injection-Safe</a>
         */
        SkipSqlInjectionInspection,
        /***
         * Encoding tranformer :native to ascii stuff, eg. 汉字 ->  \u6c49\u5b57 
         */
        Native2Ascii,
        /***
         *  Encoding tranformer :ascii to native stuff, eg. \u6c49\u5b57 -> 汉字
         */
        Ascii2Native,
        /***
         * trim all head/tail whiteSpace from a string instance.
         */
        Trim,
        /***
         * only trim head whiteSpace from a string instance. 
         */
        TrimStart,
        /***
         * only trim tail whiteSpace for a string instance. 
         */
        TrimEnd
    }
}
```

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.CharSequenceTranslator;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.UnicodeUnescaper;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Random;

/***
 * 基于Apache Common-Lang StringUtils扩展的工具类
 */
public class StringExtendUtils extends StringUtils {

    public static String stripUnicode(final String str, boolean trimUnicodeNullCodePoint) {
        final int strLen = length(str);
        if (strLen == 0) {
            return str;
        }
        int start = 0;

        while (start != strLen && isWhitespace(str.charAt(start))) {
            start++;
        }

        final String tmp = str.substring(start);
        int end = length(tmp);

        if (end == 0) {
            return tmp;
        }

        while (end != 0 && isWhitespace(tmp.charAt(end - 1))) {
            end--;
        }

        String optimized = tmp.substring(0, end);

        if (trimUnicodeNullCodePoint && optimized.length() > 0) {
            while (optimized.startsWith("\\u0000") || optimized.startsWith("\\U0000")) {
                optimized = optimized.substring("\\u0000".length());
            }
            while (optimized.endsWith("\\u0000") || optimized.endsWith("\\U0000")) {
                optimized = optimized.substring(0, optimized.length() - 6);
            }

            while (optimized.startsWith("\\xa0") || optimized.startsWith("\\XA0")) {
                optimized = optimized.substring("\\XA0".length());
            }
            //待测试
            while (optimized.endsWith("\\xa0") || optimized.endsWith("\\XA0")) {
                optimized = optimized.substring(0, optimized.length() - 4);
            }
        }

        return optimized.trim();
    }
}
```

#### JacksonStringDeserializer

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.VersionUtil;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ValueNode;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

/***
 * @author: passedbylove
 */
@Slf4j
public class JacksonStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> implements Versioned, ContextualDeserializer, AbstractJsonDeserializeSupport {

    private ConcurrentMap<String, StringOptimizing> optimizingSets = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Version version() {
        return VersionUtil.versionFor(getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

        final TreeNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

        final String propertyName = Optional.ofNullable(jp.getParsingContext().getCurrentName()).orElse("");

        if (isUnsupportedNumericNode(node)) {
            return null;
        }

        String finalValue = ((ValueNode) node).asText();

        if (finalValue == null) {
            return null;
        }
        finalValue = StringExtendUtils.stripUnicode(finalValue);

        if (finalValue == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (isDefinedInvalidCharacter(finalValue)) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            boolean SkipSqlInjectionInspection = false;

            StringOptimizing stringOptimizing = optimizingSets.get(propertyName);

            if (stringOptimizing != null) {
                final StringOptimizing.EffectFeature[] features = stringOptimizing.usingFeature();

                final boolean duplicateHalfFullWidth = Arrays.stream(features).filter(
                        item -> item == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.FullWidthToHalfWidth
                                || item == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.HalfWidthToFullWidth
                ).count() > 1;

                if (duplicateHalfFullWidth) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.FullWidthToHalfWidth and StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.HalfWidthToFullWidth can't applied to the property %s deserialization in the same times.", propertyName)});
            }

            boolean trimConflict = Arrays.stream(features).filter(item -> item == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.Trim
                    || item == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.TrimStart || item == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.TrimEnd).count() > 1;

            if (trimConflict) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.Trim and StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.TrimStart、StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.TrimEnd can't applied to the property %s deserialization in the same times. ", propertyName));
            }

            final boolean conflictEscape = Arrays.stream(features).filter(
                    item -> item == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.HtmlEscape || item == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.HtmlUnEscape
            ).count() > 1;

            if (conflictEscape) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.HtmlEscape and StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.HtmlUnEscape can't applied to the property %s deserialization in the same times. ", propertyName));
            }

            final boolean conflictAscii = Arrays.stream(features).filter(
                    item -> item == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.Native2Ascii || item == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.Ascii2Native
            ).count() > 1;

            if (conflictAscii) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.Native2Ascii and StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.Ascii2Native can't applied to the property %s deserialization in the same times. ", propertyName));
            }

            for (StringOptimizing.EffectFeature usingFeature : features) {
                if (usingFeature == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.FullWidthToHalfWidth) {
                    finalValue = toHalfWidth(finalValue);
                }

                if (usingFeature == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.HalfWidthToFullWidth) {
                    finalValue = toFullWidth(finalValue);
                }
                if (usingFeature == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.TrimUnicodeNullCodePoint) {
                    finalValue = StringExtendUtils.stripUnicode(finalValue, true);
                }
                if (usingFeature == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.SkipSqlInjectionInspection) {
                    SkipSqlInjectionInspection = true;
                }
                if (usingFeature == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.HtmlEscape) {
                    finalValue = HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(finalValue);
                }
                if (usingFeature == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.HtmlUnEscape) {
                    finalValue = HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape(finalValue);
                }
                if (usingFeature == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.Native2Ascii) {
                    finalValue = StringExtendUtils.native2Ascii(finalValue);
                }
                if (usingFeature == StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.Ascii2Native) {
                    finalValue = StringExtendUtils.ascii2Native(finalValue);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!SkipSqlInjectionInspection) {
            //check sql injection by Regxp by  <a href="https://github.com/rkpunjal/sql-injection-safe">Annotation and Utility to check if data Strings are Sql-Injection-Safe</a>
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("deserialization failed", e);
    }

        return finalValue;
}

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(final DeserializationContext context,
                                                final BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        if (property != null) {
            final StringOptimizing stringOptimizing = property.getAnnotation(StringOptimizing.class);
            if (Objects.nonNull(stringOptimizing)) {
                optimizingSets.put(property.getFullName().toString(), stringOptimizing);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 转半角的函数(DBC case)<br/><br/>
     * 全角空格为12288，半角空格为32
     * 其他字符半角(33-126)与全角(65281-65374)的对应关系是：均相差65248
     *
     * @param input 任意字符串
     * @return 半角字符串
     */
    public final String toHalfWidth(final String input) {
        final char[] c = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i] == 12288) {
                //全角空格为12288，半角空格为32
                c[i] = (char) 32;
                continue;
            }
            if (c[i] > 65280 && c[i] < 65375)
            //其他字符半角(33-126)与全角(65281-65374)的对应关系是：均相差65248
            {
                c[i] = (char) (c[i] - 65248);
            }
        }
        return new String(c);
    }

    /**
     * 转全角的方法(SBC case)<br/><br/>
     * 全角空格为12288，半角空格为32
     * 其他字符半角(33-126)与全角(65281-65374)的对应关系是：均相差65248
     *
     * @param input 任意字符串
     * @return 半角字符串
     */
    public final String toFullWidth(final String input) {
        //半角转全角：
        final char[] c = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i] == 32) {
                c[i] = (char) 12288;
                continue;
            }
            if (c[i] < 127) {
                c[i] = (char) (c[i] + 65248);
            }
        }
        return new String(c);
    }
}
```

#### AbstractJsonDeserializeSupport

```java
/**
* JSON反序列化支持工具类
*
* @author: passedbylove
* @date: Created by  2023/7/3 10:49
* @version: 1.0.0
  */
  public interface AbstractJsonDeserializeSupport {

  Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractJsonDeserializeSupport.class);
  /***
    * 如果当前字段的字符值仅仅是下列之一，将视为NULL
      */
      Set<String> treatAsNull = Sets.newHashSet("null", "undefined", "", "nil", "NaN");

  Set<String> treatAsNullIgnoreCase = Sets.newHashSet("\\u0000", "\\xa0");

  Predicate<String> whiteSpacePredicate = Pattern.compile("^\\s+$").asPredicate();

  //剔除非必要的字符

  /***
    * 剔除非必要的字符
    * @param str
    * @return
      */
      default String stripUnnecessaryChar(final String str) {
      StringExtendUtils.stripUnicode(str, true);
      return null;
      }

  /***
    * 包含已定义的无效字符（串）
    * @param ch
    * @return
      */
      default boolean isDefinedInvalidCharacter(String ch) {
      return whiteSpacePredicate.test(ch) ||
      (StringUtils.isNotBlank(ch)
      && (treatAsNull.stream().anyMatch(ch::equals)
      || treatAsNullIgnoreCase.stream().anyMatch(ch::equalsIgnoreCase)));
      }

  /***
    * 不支持的数值类型JSON Node
    * @param node
    * @return
      */
      default boolean isUnsupportedNumericNode(final TreeNode node) {
      return !(node instanceof NumericNode || node instanceof TextNode) || node instanceof NullNode;
      }
      }
```

#### TestCase

```java
public class Item {

    @StringOptimizing(usingFeature = StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.FullWidthToHalfWidth)
    public int id;
    public String itemName;
    public User owner;

    public Item() {
        super();
    }

    public Item(final int id, final String itemName, final User owner) {
        this.id = id;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    // API

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public User getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

}


public class User {
    public int id;
    @StringOptimizing(usingFeature = StringOptimizing.EffectFeature.Native2Ascii)
    public String name;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(final int id, final String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // API

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}


    final String json = "{\"id\":１０２１,\"itemName\":\"\u0000theItem\",\"owner\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"\xa0欢迎访问stackoverflow.com\"}}";

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(String.class, new LiteJacksonStringDeserializerV2());

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);

    final Item readValue = objectMapper.readValue(json, Item.class);

       System.out.printf("readValue.getId:%d\n",readValue.getId()); 
       //output:1021
       System.out.printf("readValue.getItemName:%s\n",readValue.getItemName()); 
       //output:theItem
    System.out.printf("readValue.getOwner().getName():%s\n",readValue.getOwner().getName());
       //output:\u6b22\u8fce\u8bbf\u95eestackoverflow.com
```